# How do I change the license key for an installed copy of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, license-key, cloud

We have a number of Amazon EC2 instances with Visual Studio 2010 installed on them.  The license we are using has a fixed number of seats, all of which are being utilized at the moment.

I've created a new instance for an additional developer on our team (cloned from an image with VS 2010 already installed on it), but I need to use a different license key for the Visual Studio 2010 installation on his instance.

How do I change the license key for an installed copy of Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From iMohanG:

> Method 1: Change the serial number after Visual Studio 2010
>   installation
>
> 1. Go to Control Panel → Programs and Features, locate and highlight Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate/Premium/Professional installation, and click on Uninstall/Change button.
> 2. Upgrade Visual Studio 2010 Product Key for Activation
> 3. A Visual Studio setup maintenance screen should be shown. After clicking Next button, an option to enter a valid serial number to upgrade product license is available.
> 4. Enter the upgrade key accordingly, and click on Activate button. No re-installation required.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you provide a link to the source site?

Comment: The link has some questionable material that probably isn't appropriate for this forum.  They are well known exploits, nothing too nefarious, but I am not totally comfortable posting here.  I didn't alter any of the text, though, so you can do a string search to find the source.  Did you try the process? Did it work?